# Timeline Visual with exact specifications needed

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to look for a visual with the following specifications:

- Job usage timeline (bar graph like)
- Jobs can be part of a group
- When two or more jobs of the same group overlap (timestamp) they should be
  displayed in the next line
- Timestamps can be days, hours, minutes and seconds precise Tooltips (hover over QuickInfo)

Here are the ones I've tried so far and why they didn't work:

- R-Script: hc_vistime - (Couldn't be displayed)
- R-Script: gg_vistime - (No tooltips)
- Gantt - (Timestamps could only be days exact)
- Craydec Timelines - (Overlaps would not start new line)

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am having this exact requirement, I am currently using MAQ Gantt Chart in Power BI